# how do add css-classname to the whitelist?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sanitize

I have a string with html tags:

```
html = '</span class="repository-content"> ... </span>'
```

I need to allow a only specific name for the css class. I use gem [sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize).
This code works well and allows any name for the css class:

```
Sanitize.fragment(
  html,
  elements: ['span'],
  attributes: { 'span' => ['class'] }
)
```

But need to allow only the class `repository-content`. Any other class name must not pass.
How can this be done? any proposal

Answer (score 0):

If instead of inputting html, you input the `...` part and build the `span` like this:

```
content_tag(:span, ..., class: "repository-content")
```

then you can write ruby to handle the logic of what to do if the class is not `"repository-content"`.

You may have to sanitize the `...`, but you probably won't have to sanitize the output of `content_tag`.